# How to find which item in a JSON list has the greatest value for two given attributes in Python?

Tags: python, json, list, max

If I have a json list, how can I know which item corresponds to two greatest values of a list ? 
for example if I have a json list :

````
      "Z coude": 20,
     "X poignet":25 ,
      "Z poignet":30 ,
     "X Main":70 ,
     "Z Main": 10,
     "Reward pied":12 ,
    "Reward Tibia":14 ,
      "Reward Cuisse":15,
     "Reward appuiCuisse":16 ,
     "Reward Tête":14 ,
    "Reward Torse":87 ,
     "Reward coude": 89,
      "Reward poignet":10 ,
     "Reward main":30 ,
     "Reward bras":33 ,
         "Reward":17 ,
    "Reward knee":10 ```
````

I want to have the list corresponding to the max of "Reward poignet" and "Reward" at the same time? 
I have tried this but it doesn't seem to work.

`result = max(epmaxinfos, key=lambda ev: ev['Reward Poignet', 'Reward'])`

for example, I want to have the list values corresponding to the maximum  sum of "reward" and "reward poignet"

Thank you

Comment: What you showed is a dict, not a list, so from the context I infer that you have in fact a list of dicts and want to find… exactly what? _the max of "Reward poignet" and "Reward" at the same time_ does not make much sense because it is possible that one item in the list has the bigger "Reward" and another one has biggest "Reward poignet"; what should be returned in this case? Both records? None?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is actually a dictionary.

You can do the following -

```
d = {
   "X coude":15 ,
   "Z coude": 20,
   "X poignet":25 ,
   "Z poignet":30 ,
   "X Main":70 ,
   "Z Main": 10,
   "Reward pied":12 ,
   "Reward Tibia":14 ,
   "Reward Cuisse":15,
   "Reward appuiCuisse":16 ,
   "Reward Tête":14 ,
   "Reward Torse":87 ,
   "Reward coude": 89,
   "Reward poignet":10 ,
   "Reward main":30 ,
   "Reward bras":33 ,
   "Reward":17 ,
   "Reward knee":10 
}
num_res = 2
results = [k for k,v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: -x[1])[:num_res]]
```

Comment: I guess the reverse option is to just to just slice from `[-2:]` and keep the sorting key as `x[1]`: `k for k,v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[-num_res:]]`

Comment: You are right, there are multiple options, to achieve that

Comment: Actually, I don't want to sort the values, I want to have the list values corresponding to the maximum of sum of "reward" and reward poignet"

Comment: Please post in the original post the expected output because the description is not clear

Answer (score 0):

`max` will only give you the highest single value, not the top N values. Also `key=lambda ev: ev['Reward Poignet', 'Reward']` will not work as a key. You need to pass a key function than uses the dictionaries values for comparison. One way would be to do `max(epmaxinfos.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])`.

If you want top N values, use [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) from [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

> Return a list of the n most common elements and their counts from the most common to the least. If n is omitted or None, most_common() returns all elements in the counter. Elements with equal counts are ordered in the order first encountered:

**Demo**

```
from collections import Counter

d = {
   "X coude":15 ,
   "Z coude": 20,
   "X poignet":25 ,
   "Z poignet":30 ,
   "X Main":70 ,
   "Z Main": 10,
   "Reward pied":12 ,
   "Reward Tibia":14 ,
   "Reward Cuisse":15,
   "Reward appuiCuisse":16 ,
   "Reward Tête":14 ,
   "Reward Torse":87 ,
   "Reward coude": 89,
   "Reward poignet":10 ,
   "Reward main":30 ,
   "Reward bras":33 ,
   "Reward":17 ,
   "Reward knee":10 
}

print(Counter(d).most_common(2))
```

**Output**

```
[('Reward coude', 89), ('Reward Torse', 87)]
```

If you just want the reward names, unpack the first item in a list comprehension:

```
print([k for k, _ in Counter(d).most_common(2)])
# ['Reward coude', 'Reward Torse']
```

Comment: Thank you ! Actually, I don't want to sort the values, I want to have the list values corresponding to the maximum of sum of "reward" and reward poignet"

Comment: @MarouaBenzarti Sorry I don't understand. You will need to give an example in your question.